# Filtering item from nested object array in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I have looked for a while now for examples but I can't find anything similar and my understanding of the filter function is lacking, any help is much, much appreciated. I'm trying to remove elements from the object where the nested items label === undefined.

```
this.items = [ // main MenuItem[] object (contains entire menu)
  {
    label: this.headingLabel, visible: this.booleanPipe.transform(this.labelVisible),
    items: [ // headings of the menu sit in navbar, a MenuItem[][] two dimensional array
      [
        {
          label: this.subMenuLabel, visible: this.booleanPipe.transform(this.labelVisible), separator: true,
          items: [ // items that need to be removed if they are undefined, another MenuItem[] object, potentially need to remove only some of its elements
            { label: this.subMenuItemLabel, visible: this.booleanPipe.transform(this.labelVisible) },
            { label: this.subMenuItemLabel, visible: this.booleanPipe.transform(this.labelVisible) },
            { label: undefined, visible: this.booleanPipe.transform(this.labelVisible) },
            { label: this.subMenuItemLabel, visible: this.booleanPipe.transform(this.labelVisible) },
            { label: this.subMenuItemLabel, visible: this.booleanPipe.transform(this.labelVisible) },
            { label: undefined, visible: this.booleanPipe.transform(this.labelVisible) }
          ]
        },
      ],
      [
        {
          label: subMenuLabel, visible: this.booleanPipe.transform(this.labelVisible), separator: true,
          items: [
            { label: subMenuItemLabel, visible: this.booleanPipe.transform(this.labelVisible) },
            { label: subMenuItemLabel, visible: this.booleanPipe.transform(this.labelVisible) },
            { label: subMenuItemLabel, visible: this.booleanPipe.transform(this.labelVisible) }
          ]
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
  ...
```

I was able to remove elements from the main object where label is undefined with this:

```
        this.items = this.items.filter(obj => obj.label !== undefined);
```

But I am not able to figure out how to nest another filter, or map, or find... not really sure how.. to be able to access the nested items and check their labels for undefined and remove them!

**EDIT1:**
The this.items object is a MenuItem[] array. MenuItem is a PrimeNG class. It has the following definition:

```
export interface MenuItem {
    label?: string;
    icon?: string;
    command?: (event?: any) => void;
    url?: string;
    routerLink?: any;
    queryParams?: { [k: string]: any };
    items?: MenuItem[]|MenuItem[][];
    expanded?: boolean;
    disabled?: boolean;
    visible?: boolean;
    target?: string;
    routerLinkActiveOptions?: any;
    separator?: boolean;
    badge?: string;
    badgeStyleClass?: string;
    style?:any;
    styleClass?:string;
    title?: string;
    id?: string;
    automationId?: any;
}
```

In order to construct the MegaMenu component you have to define your structure in the typescript file and I'm unable to deviate from this as it's not my call. I am also unable to chose another menu component from PrimeNG's library. I hope my further explanation helps, sorry if I was not clear enough at first. I wanted to focus in on the issue specifically without over complicating the question.

```
this.items = [ //main MenuItem[] contains the entire menu
  {
    label: label1, visible: this.booleanPipe.transform(this.labelVisible),
    items: [ //nested MenuItem[][] contains the headings and each individual menu list for headings
      [
        {
          label: this.label2, visible: this.booleanPipe.transform(this.labelVisible), separator: true,
          items: [ //another MenuItem[] (contains dropdowns, subheadings etc)
            { label: this.label3, visible: this.booleanPipe.transform(this.labelVisible) },
```

The main reason for wanting to be able to remove the inner most nested items object is because angular still renders a blank spot in the menu even if you make it visible: false. This makes the menu look really, really ugly and fragmented.

Thanks for all the suggestions so far and helping close some of the gaps in my knowledge, I will try to implement all suggested ideas tomorrow and report back. I hope my edits offer more clarity.

**EDIT:** 
I'm signing off for the day, latest attempt I had this but it didn't work:

```
   for (let item of this.items) {
      for (let subItem of item.items) {
        subItem = (subItem as (MenuItem)[]).filter(obj => obj.label !== undefined);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Is this the maximum depth, or may the array be deeper nested?

Comment: @bambam this is the maximum depth, it's just longer and I omitted some of the length to not be redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use recursive calls like this:

```
    private filterItems(items:Array){
        return this.items.filter(obj => obj.label !== undefined)
           .forEach(item=> if(item.items) {item.items=this.filterArray(item.items)};
    }
```

with the first call of `items=this.filterItems(items)`

Probably this needs some fixing as I wrote it here without compilators help, but it should give you a very solid start.

Answer (score 1):

Use `reduce` to create single list containinga all elements and filter then.

Comment: I need the structure to stay the way it is though, because PrimeNG MegaMenu utilizes it in order to create the menu. The data is being loaded dynamically and I need remove the undefined elements after the menu data is loaded so that they don't show up as blanks in the menu.

Comment: Then use recursive calls when `items` exists.

Answer (score 1):

just so we're clear, your data looks like:

```
interface Item {
    label?: string;
    visible: boolean;
}
interface MiddleItem {
    label?: string;
    visible: boolean;
    separator: boolean;
    items?: Item[];
}
interface TopItem {
    label?: string;
    visible: boolean;
    items?: MiddleItem[][];
}
interface Scope {
    items?: TopItem[];
}
```

Based on your sample code, you want to modify your original data.  That makes the algorithm slightly simpler (alternately, you can deep-copy first, then do this)

Step by step, you want to:

- Check if the label is undefined
- if so, remove that entry
- if not, process the child items in the 'same' way

It would be super easy to do it recursively if you had just one interface, but your child items are all different signatures, and you know your depth, so lets spell it out rather that doing anything fancy.

starting from the entry point:

```
processScope(this);

function processScope(scope: Scope) {
    if(!scope.items) return;
    scope.items = scope.items.filter(processTop); // basically your initial start
}

// this function gets called for each array entry in top.items
// normally you see filter as using just the simplified boolean test function
// but here we are going to have it preform a side effect - modifying the contents!
// splitting this out to its own named function makes it easier to read / document
function processTop(top: TopItem): boolean {
    if (!top.label) return false; // do not include in filtered array

    if (top.items) {
        top.items = top.items
            .map(processMiddleArr)  // process each subarray
            .filter(middleArr => middleArr.length !== 0); // map might have replaced the subarray with an empty array - filter those out

    return true;  // include in filtered array
}

// this gets called for each array entry in top.items
// since top.items is a two dimensional array, this is just another array to iterate
function processMiddleArr(middleArr: MiddleItem[]): MiddleItem[] {
    return middleArr.filter(processMiddle);
}

function processMiddle(middle: MiddleItem): boolean {
    if (middle.label === undefined) return false; // do not include in filtered array

    // here's another side effect, filtering the lowest level item list
    if (middle.items) middle.items = middle.items.filter(processItem);

    return true; // include in filtered array        
}

// broken out into its own function for consistency with the above filter calls
// this would be fine to do inline as middle.items.filter(it => !!item.label)
function processItem(item: Item): boolean {
    if (item.label === undefined) return false; // do not include in filtered array

    return true; // include in filtered array
}
```